# Should these two MDX queries return identical results?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx

I have two MDX queries (the basis for which come from Excel's CUBEVALUE() function).  I expect the output of both of these queries to be identical, but they're not.

Consider this account structure:

```
some accounts ...
  Account A
      Account B
      Account C
      Account D
      Account E
other accounts ...
```

My Account dimension is defined using Account Intelligence -- it's also a Parent/Child dimension.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT [Measures].[Actual] ON 0 
FROM [MYSYSTEM] 
WHERE (
    {[Account].[Accounts].&[Account B], [Account].[Accounts].&[Account C]}, 
    [Time].[Year - Month].&[2011-12-01T00:00:00]
)
```

Returns the aggregate [Measures].[Actual] value for **Account A** (yes, the parent), not the values for Accounts B and C in the specified time interval.

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT [Measures].[Actual] ON 0 
FROM [MYSYSTEM] 
WHERE 
    { 
    ([Account].[Accounts].&[Account B], [Time].[Year - Month].&[2011-12-01T00:00:00]),
    ([Account].[Accounts].&[Account C], [Time].[Year - Month].&[2011-12-01T00:00:00])
    }
```

Returns what I expect -- the  [Measures].[Actual] value for Accounts B and C in the specified time interval.

My question is this -- is there something I'm missing conceptually about MDX as a language?  Am I wrong to think that these queries should generally return the same value?  Does this point to a flaw in how I laid out my Account Dimension?

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with you dimension, i replicated the queries with my cubes and got the same result both times:

```
select [Measures].[Amount] on 0,
[Account].[Account Type].[Account Type] on 1
from [Cube]
where (
{[Account].[Accounts].&[4],[Account].[Accounts].&[5]}
,[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2002]&[11]
)

select [Measures].[Amount] on 0,
[Account].[Account Type].[Account Type] on 1
from [Cube]
 where {
([Account].[Accounts].&[4],[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2002]&[11]),
([Account].[Accounts].&[5],[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2002]&[11])
}
```

Could it have something to do with the use of account intelligence?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174759(v=sql.100).aspx
I haven´t used that myself..

Comment: +1.  Thanks a bunch for taking the trouble to replicate this in your environment.  That's what I'm thinking.  I'm probably going to restructure my whole cube pretty soon, moving the works from SSAS Multidimensional to Tabular mode.  I'm willing to bet that when I make that change, I'll see the behavior of the queries change as well.